# Determining the minimum value of the function $y = x + 2\sqrt{x^2 - \sqrt{2}x + 1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, analytic-geometry, maxima-minima

I am curious whether there is an algebraic verification for $y = x + 2\sqrt{x^2 - \sqrt{2}x + 1}$ having its minimum value of  $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}$ at $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$. I have been told the graph of it is that of a hyperbola.

Comment: there is a straight-forward procedure using calculus -- do you know it? or do you need the argument from analytic geometry instead?

Comment: @Jam why not differentiate straight up, why do you need implicit?

Comment: @gt6989b Sorry you're right; I misread the equation. Normal differentiation would work.

Comment: @gt6989b  I was requesting an argument without Calculus.

Comment: Not entirely sure whether this helps but the problem is the same as showing that the minimum of $x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}+2\left(x^2-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}x+\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Without derivatives,

Considering the functions

$$
f(x,y)=y-x-2\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt 2 x-1} = 0\\
y = \lambda
$$

Their intersection is at the solution for

$$
f(x,\lambda)=\lambda-x-2\sqrt{x^2-\sqrt 2 x-1} = 0
$$

or squaring

$$
(x-\lambda)^2-2(x^2-\sqrt 2 x-1)=0
$$

Solving for $x$ we have

$$
x = \frac{1}{3} \left(2 \sqrt{2}\pm 2 \sqrt{\lambda ^2-\sqrt{2} \lambda -1}-\lambda\right)
$$

but at tangency between $f(x,y)=0, y =  \lambda$ we have

$$
\lambda ^2-\sqrt{2} \lambda -1 = 0\Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}\right)
$$

as the feasible minimum.

[image]

Comment: I was requesting an "algebraic solution."

Comment: @Adelyn Please. Show me what is not algebraic in my answer.

Comment: How is it not an algebraic solution? The square root there says that $\lambda^2-\sqrt{2}\lambda - 1 \ge 0$, which, together with $\lambda\ge 0$ gives you the conclusion.

Comment: @Cesareo I don't quite follow what you're doing when you say "but at tangency between $f(x,y)=0$, $y=\lambda$". Is there a name of the technique you're using here?

Comment: @Jam See the plot attached. Tangency is a clean concept. Only a common point between two curves.

Comment: Or simply vanishing of the discriminant in the resolvent equation.

Comment: I think that when you say "tangency," you're using Calculus.

Comment: If that is not what you meant by "tangency," please offer an alternate interpretation for it.

Comment: @Cesareo I think I see how you've done it. I think it's a bit conceptually easier to see it as in **egreg's** comment, where $x=+2\sqrt{\lambda^2-\sqrt{2}\lambda-1}$  and $x=-2\sqrt{\lambda^2-\sqrt{2}\lambda-1}$ specify the left and right branches of the hyperbola, and these only meet when $+2\sqrt{\lambda^2-\sqrt{2}\lambda-1}=-2\sqrt{\lambda^2-\sqrt{2}\lambda-1}$. Although I think this is roughly equivalent to your answer as $x=\frac{1}{3} \left(2 \sqrt{2}\pm 2 \sqrt{\lambda ^2-\sqrt{2} \lambda -1}-\lambda\right)$ specifies the two $x$ solutions for $y=\lambda$ (and we want only 1 solution).

Comment: @Adelyn The proof doesn't use calculus. You can see that if you work through it. By "tangency", Cesareo means that the curves meet at only one point (which is the case at the minimum). Cesareo's shown how to find the $2$ solutions for the intersections between the curves but it's not too hard to see when you would only have $1$ solution (i.e. find the tangent).

Comment: @Jam I think what he meant was to define a function $f$ of two variables by $f(x,y) = y - x - 2\sqrt{x^{2} - \sqrt{2} \, x - 1}$ and to find the intersection of the two "curves" $f(x,y)=0$ and $y=\lambda$.

Comment: @Jam  I get the intersection of the two curves to be ...

Comment: @Jam ...  $\sqrt{2}\left(1 \pm\sqrt{\lambda^{2} - \sqrt{2}\lambda + 2}\right) - \lambda$.

Comment: @Jam  I guess that the curves meet at only one point for the solution to $\lambda^{2} - \sqrt{2}\lambda + 2 = 0$ ... but it has no real solution.

Answer (score 3):

One of the approaches may be as follows:

Suppose there exists some $a$ which is the minimum. Then:

$$
\begin{align}
x + 2\sqrt{x^2 - \sqrt2 x+1} &= a \\
2\sqrt{x^2 - \sqrt2 x+1} &= a-x
\end{align}
$$

Square both sides:

$$
(a-x)^2 = 4x^2 - 4\sqrt2x + 4
$$

Applying some transformations you can get:

$$
3x^2 + x(2a-4\sqrt2) + 4 -a^2 =0
$$

Now you want the discriminant to be equal to zero which means only one root will exist, so:

$$
D = 16a^2 - 16\sqrt2a-16 = a^2 - \sqrt2a - 1 =0
$$

The equation in terms of $a$ has two solutions:

$$
a_1 = {1-\sqrt3 \over \sqrt2} \\
a_2 = {1+\sqrt{3} \over \sqrt2}
$$

If you plug them into the initial equation only one of them is going to produce a valid statement. Therefore that will be you minimum, which appears to be ${1+\sqrt3 \over \sqrt2}$

Comment: This is an elementary explanation. Thanks.

Comment: You have a typographical error.

Comment: $D = a^{2} - \sqrt{2}a - 1 = 0$.

Comment: @Adelyn You are right, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "non-calculus" way that plays the whole show back to AMGM. It is a bit cumbersome but works.

I prefer giving all stepwise substitutions to show how to bring the whole expression back to hyperbolic functions where AMGM suddenly gives all. The basic idea behind it is that $\cosh t = \sqrt{\sinh^2 t + 1}$:

$$\color{blue}{y=} x + 2\sqrt{x^2 - \sqrt{2}x + 1}$$
$$x^2 - \sqrt{2}x + 1 = (x - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2 + 1 - \frac{1}{2} = (x - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2 +  \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\color{green}{u =x - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}  \Rightarrow \color{blue}{y=} u + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} +2\sqrt{u^2+\frac{1}{2}} = \color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + u + \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{2} u\right)^2 + 1}}$$
$$\color{green}{v = \sqrt{2} u} \Rightarrow \color{blue}{y =} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} v + \sqrt{2}\sqrt{v^2 + 1} = \color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \sqrt{2} \left(\boxed{ \frac{v}{2} + \sqrt{v^2 + 1}} \right)}$$
$$\color{green}{v = \sinh t} \Rightarrow \boxed{ \frac{\sinh t}{2} + \cosh t} = \frac{e^t - e^{-t}}{4} + \frac{e^t + e^{-t}}{2} = \frac{3}{4}e^t + \frac{1}{4} e^{-t}  \boxed{\stackrel{AMGM}{\geq}} \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} = \boxed{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$
Setting $\color{green}{w= e^t}$, equality holds for
$$3w = \frac{1}{w} \stackrel{w>0}{\Leftrightarrow} w =\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \Rightarrow 
\color{blue}{y \geq} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \sqrt{2}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left( 1 + \sqrt{3}\right)}$$

Note that
$$\left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left( 1 + \sqrt{3}\right) \right)^2 =\frac{1}{2}\left( 1 + 2\sqrt{3} + 3\right) =  2 + \sqrt{3} $$

Backwards substitution yield $x$:
$$\color{green}{t =} \ln \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \color{green}{-\ln \sqrt{3}} \Rightarrow \color{green}{v =} \sinh t = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3}}{2} = \color{green}{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}$$  $$ \Rightarrow \color{green}{x =} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}v+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \left(- \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \right) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \color{green}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}}$$

Comment: You decided to complete the square on the expression $x^{2}-\sqrt{2}\,x+1$ just to get an expression similar to a hyperbolic sine so that you could use the identity $\cosh^{2}t-\sinh^{2}t=1$ and the Arithmetic-Geometric-Mean Inequality.

Comment: From there, you planned to find the number in the domain at which the minimum value was obtained.

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: @Adelyn: Almost correct. I was heading for an expression in hyperbolic functions as it felt helpful. But at that point in time I still was not sure how to proceed. While I was pondering about estimating the hyperbolic expression, I realized that AMGM removes the exponentials, gives a sharp estimation and a condition, when equality occurs. I tried that and it worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Scale and shift
$$\begin{align}u&=\sqrt{2}x-1&v&=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y-\tfrac{1}{2}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Then it is just as well to minimize
$$v=\tfrac{u}{2}+\sqrt{u^2+1}\text{.}$$
with respect to $u$.

Use the stereographic projection
$$u=\frac{2t}{t^2-1}\text{.}$$
Then it is just as well to minimize
$$v=1+\frac{t+2}{t^2-1}=1+\frac{3}{2(t-1)}-\frac{1}{2(t+1)}$$
over $t^2>1\text{.}$
Use the Cayley transform
$$s=\frac{t-1}{t+1}\text{.}$$
Then it is just as well to minimize
$$v=\frac{3}{4s}+\frac{s}{4}$$
over $s>0$. Rescale
$$\begin{align}w&=2\frac{v}{\sqrt{3}}&r&=\frac{s}{\sqrt{3}}\text{.}\end{align}$$

Then it is just as well to minimize
$$w=\frac{r+\tfrac{1}{r}}{2}$$
over $r>0$.
But by the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality,
$$w\geq 1$$
with equality iff $r=1$. Retracing the steps gives
$$\begin{align}x&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&y&=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\text{.}
\end{align}$$